# Use SOQL to select records filtered by lookup field

Tags: soql, lookup-filter

I did some SOQL queries that cannot return what I want, I wrote:

```
List <Custom_Opportunity__c> buffer = [SELECT id,VD_Owner__c FROM Custom_Opportunity__c WHERE VD_Owner__c =: VDOwner.id];

System.debug('The buffer size is: ' + buffer.size()); printed 0 for the size of the list.
```

VD_Owner__c is a lookup field to lookup User. I have checked that the variable VDOwner does contain data and VDOwner.id is the one I want. From report, with the filter, I can see that there are 4 records of the object Custom_Opportunity__c under that particular User. However, with this SOQL, it returned 0 for the size.

I do not know what as wrong. Is there anyone that can point it out why it did not give me what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Is it happening in sandbox or production? I have faced similar issues in one of my sandboxes.

Comment: In sandbox. Do you mean that in production this kind of problem will not happen?

Comment: I tried to select all the records in the object Custom_Opportunity__c or select a particular record. It just returns 0 for size as well. However, I used SOQL to get the Users info for the VDOwner and the info was correct.

Comment: Can you check using debug if value that is there in VDOwner.id is infact a userRecord? run the query in query editor using  the value you get in VDOwner.id

Comment: This is just debugging at it's simplest.  Isolate the problem by confirming whether your query returns anything without a WHERE clause, whether the VDOWner.id has the value you expect, and whether the query works when you hard code the VDOwner.id.

Comment: The variable VDOwner does contain the content. Using query editor it works to get the wanted records.

Comment: However, when using in the real code, for the object Custom_Opportunity__c, I cannot get anything even without WHERE.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, some stupid things were happening with my queries in sandbox, but for some reason same queries were working with reports. They worked perfectly fine with prod.

Comment: Is this code running 'with sharing' or 'without sharing'?

Comment: If only Sandbox does not work on the queries but work on Production, that is fine. I mean finally we are going to deploy it to production. However, I am worried about this is not going to work in Production either. So far I am sure that any SOQL query regarding the particular object Custom_Opportunity__c would return nothing.

Comment: I had a try on both 'with sharing' and 'without sharing', still return nothing on my SOQL query.

Comment: The most likely cause is like @NickCook has mentioned is with sharing. Are you running the code and checking the SOQL as a same user ? The user who is running the code might not have access to those records and while querying you might be on Sys admin profile. I dont think they would act differently in sandbox and prodn

Comment: I wrote a class to execute the SOQL queries and I used a test class to see whether it was working. I haven't put it on any other real class or trigger. I tried to add both 'with sharing' and 'without sharing' on both the class and the test class. So far, the queries still return nothing.

Comment: I had a try to apply the class on the trigger I planned to use. The system debug returned the correct number I want. Therefore, that is the problem with testing class?

Comment: Ah get it.. Your test class will not use existing records, it will only run based on the records you create within the test class unless you use the attribute seeAlldata= true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are facing is because unless you are using the annotation `SeeAllData= true` in your test class the organizations data will not be accessed by the test class.

> IsTest(SeeAllData=true) Annotation
>
> For Apex code saved using SalesforceAPI version 24.0 and later, use
>   the isTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation to grant test classes and
>   individual test methods access to all data in the organization,
>   including pre-existing data that the test didn’t create. Starting with
>   Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0, test methods don’t
>   have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm

It is a best practice to create your own test data in your test classes as the data in different environments would differ and your test classes could fail. Refer the post http://www.laceysnr.com/seealldata-why-i-think-you-shouldnt-use/ for more info

Also there are records of some objects which are available for test class even if the seeAllData = true annotation is not set like your User, profile, Organization objects. More info is available at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm

> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and
>   later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data
>   in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and
>   custom settings data, and can only access data that they create.
>   However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata
>   objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User Profile
>
>   - Organization
>   - AsyncApexJob
>   - CronTrigger
>   - RecordType
>   - ApexClass
>   - ApexTrigger
>   - ApexComponent
>   - ApexPage
>
> Whenever possible, you should create test data
>    for each test. You can disable this restriction by annotating your
>    test class or test method with the IsTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation.

In your case you need to create data for `Custom_Opportunity__c` in your test class with ownerid as the value you have in `VDOwner.id`. I am not sure how you are getting the value into `VDOwner.id`, you should build your test class data such that it satisfies different conditions in your test class. You could have different test methods to check different branches of the code.

Comment: or OP should create test record with owner `VDOwner.id`

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel quite sorry that I forgot that in test class I have to make the records for the testing. I actually knew it. Just forgot...

Comment: No Worries :) It happens. Glad i was of help